# Update hosted website files directly from github

Tags: github, webserver, hosting

Is there any way to update my website (php) files (hosted on godaddy server) directly from GitHub?

Comment: look on this..http://markdotto.com/2011/11/02/how-to-deploy-sites-via-github/...

Comment: What is missing for this answer to be unselected?

Comment: You had selected the right answer below.

Comment: You still have not selected the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can [edit file from the GitHub web interface](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/).
Since yesterday, you even can [upload new files from the same interface](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories).

In both case, that will trigger a [pushEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) that you can associate to a [WebHook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/). If you have on that godaddy server a [listener for that push event](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858), you will be able to pull from your GitHub repo and update your website.
See for instance the project [`fiddus/github-webhooks-listener`](https://github.com/fiddus/github-webhooks-listener).